# What post hoc test should I run for a significant interaction in a two-way unbalanced ANOVA?

Tags: r, anova, post-hoc, unbalanced-classes

I have data with two factors (`Category` and `Treatment`) and each factor has two levels (`A` and `B`; `1` and `2`, respectively). The sample size for the combinations of factors and levels is unbalanced though (n = 3, 3, 6, and 6). Based on my search of the internet, I need to run a two-way unbalanced ANOVA with type III sums of squares (since I am interested in interactions). I used the following code in `R` to run the ANOVA:

```
Anova(lm(arcsin.mort ~  Category * Treatment, data = my.data,
         contrasts=list(Category=contr.sum, Treatment=contr.sum), type=3))
```

Can someone confirm that I did this properly? I am uncertain about the contrasts. If so, both factors and their interaction are significant. What post hoc can I run for the interaction since my data are unbalanced?

Comment: Have a look at the [`lsmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsmeans/vignettes/using-lsmeans.pdf). Also could you add to your post that you use the `Anova()` function from the `car` package?

Comment: Since your effects each have 1df, I don't see why any follow-up tests would be called for. If the interaction is significant you might want to test simple effects.